# Facebook Open Graph/ dynamic content

Tags: php, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I have been trying to get Open Graph working on my site, but I am having some issues. Here is what I am having trouble with.

I am placing the associated meta tags in my header section. I want to link the meta tag with dynamic content. For instance:

`<meta property="og:title" content="< ?php echo ['title']; ?>" />`

*title* comes from a database for my blog. However, the PHP and HTML associated with this title are after the header section so it seems like I am never going to fetch my data.

I tried placing the meta tags in the body of my document but it seems like html does not recognize the meta tags then.

So in summary, how do I link the dynamic content that is being pulled from my database after my header?

Comment: why not pull the content before the header? <meta> tags need to go in the <head> for them to be read correctly.

Comment: The content is embedded in a repeat region. So I think I need the body info such that I can associate the "Like" with the correct post.